# Confusion with virtualenvs and Python packages

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

In my python program (run by a virtualenv using python3.5), I need to use the Pillow library to process an image.

> ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'

tells me that Pillow is not installed in the virtualenv.

But, when I run `pip install Pillow`, I get back:

> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

If the `pip` I am using is from the virtualenv, then why is it looking in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to check if the package is already installed?

Just to make sure, I run `type python` and `type pip` to confirm that these 2 programs are from my virtualenv, and they are:

> python is hashed (/home/nelson/.virtualenvs/MainEnv/bin/python)
>
> pip is hashed (/home/nelson/.virtualenvs/MainEnv/bin/pip)

`sudo` was not used when creating the virtualenv (I know because this had already caused problems for me) or when trying to `pip install`; so where is the flaw in this logic? How can I install Pillow in my virtualenv / How can I import Pillow?

Comment: Did you create virtual environment with `--system-site-packages` option?

Comment: @falsetru yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the virtual environment with `--system-site-packages`, the virtual environment has access to the global site-packages modules.

You need to re-create the virtual environment without `--system-site-packages` option if you don't want that.

Comment: This entire time I thought `--system-site-packages` just made a copy of the packages for the virtualenv. Thank you so much!

Comment: This did solve my problem of installing Pillow to the virtualenv, but I still cannot import it.

Comment: @Nelson, Please post a separated question with detail error message.

Answer (score 1):

Pillow is a fork of PIL. Hence `from PIL import Image`. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/tutorial.html