# Cannot import python package installed to virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I installed the python package Pillow to my virtualenv, but cannot import it. `pip list | grep Pillow` shows that it has been installed, and the virtualenv has been activated, but `import Pillow` still returns:

> ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'

The virtualenv was created with

`virtualenv -p python3.5 MainEnv`

Pillow was installed with

`pip install Pillow`

Why can I not import the installed package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion with virtualenvs and Python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859948/confusion-with-virtualenvs-and-python-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you pip install as Pillow, but import as PIL:

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/gui/how-to-use-pillow